# Need help to create mapreduce for dataset of malicious urls

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, dataset, data-mining

I am working on my final year project where we have to create a an app to detect malicious urls. We have to find patterns between all urls. We have a big dataset which takes a very long time to match a url with other urls.

Now we are thinking to move over project to hadoop, but we don't get how to make a mapreduce for our java project and dataset  and move it to hadoop.

Please help us to create a mapreduce for our program and dataset.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't started anything, try doing it with Apache Spark instead of MapReduce. There are a bunch of great tutorials out there that'll tell you how to get started.

Comment: What about the performance of spark in comparison to mapreduce? Is it good?

Comment: I'd say it's far better.

Comment: I'd say it's about the same. Performance depends a lot on your programming skills, and how much overhead you get from stacking too many layers of APIs. Spark is the hype because the code tends to be a lot less *verbose*. You write much fewer lines.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce is *not* suitable for pairwise comparisons.

It's meant to "map" all objects the same way. To work on pairs in a strict MR you would have to massively duplicate your data. That is not a good idea, as the resulting data transfer will kill performance.

Pairwise comparison problems generally do not scale well.

If you really want to be scalable, think of a smart way to avoid comparing all URLs with some good filters. Maybe you can do this filtering (and process the remaining pairs) with MapReduce.